# Is there a "perfect" diff algorithm?

Tags: diff

Is there such thing as a diff algorithm that does not make any mistakes? One that knows exactly which letters were removed and which letters where inserted in all occasions?

If one doesn't exist, is it impossible or just too difficult?

Comment: Well, it depends what you mean by "mistake". There's no way for a computer to tell which * was deleted when **** became ***, for example.

Comment: what do you mean by "what letters were removed and were inserted"? Do you mean tracking changes? or do you mean taking the insertions/deletions to be the set of changes that minimizes the total difference between the two strings? If the latter, you might find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance interesting.

Comment: so, to track the changes perfectly i'll have to implement it on the editor itself?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, because there are, in general, multiple sequences of edits that could have taken you from original to final.

Comment: But that's not really the issue. What you look for in an algorithm is the "minimal" mapping (that is, the mapping with minimal cost) from string1 to string2.

Answer (score 0):

A diff algorithm, looking that original and new text, can't tell the real sequence of edits.  So it can't know if you moved ABC from one place to another, or deleted it one and inserted in another.  Conventional diff in this case simply tells you that something was deleted in one place, and something else (it doesn't even know its the same) was inserted somewhere else.

One can build a tool to make educated guesses as to a plausible set of edits.  Our [Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) takes advantage of code structure and similarities of code fragments to guess that code blocks got moved rather than insert/deleted, even in the face of changing variable names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition issue.

Yes: it is always possible to find the perfect difference between two files in the meaning of: what is different between the two.

No: You probably want to know for instance WHICH of the `{` you have removed, and that can be too complicated, as there is no recollection of what happened afterwards.